# gridview not updating after table alter

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, gridview, oracle11g

the below code is what i've written to populate a gridview with the values from the oracle database when i click a button.
the problem im facing is that, when i delete rows in the table from "sqlplus" manually and then click the button it is still showing the values that i enterd previously and not an empty grid.im quite new to gridview so please help me out

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string v =System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["harish"].ConnectionString;
    con = new OracleConnection(v);
    con.Open(); 
    cmd = new OracleCommand("select *  from leave_module1 order by name", con);
    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    GridView1.DataSource=dr;
    GridView1.DataBind();
    con.Close();
    dr.Close();




}
```

Comment: Did you commit the changes in sqlplus?

Comment: Have you debugged it to make sure the query isn't actually returning anything?

Comment: @nunespascal i deleted all the rows in sqlplus and also checked it with select command..it came no rows selected

Comment: @CodingGorilla:it is not returng any rows in sqlplus.

Comment: @HarishViswanathan But is your `OracleCommand` actually returning the results?  The problem may have nothing to do with the datagrid, it could be a caching problem or a lack of commit or something at the database side of things.

Comment: @CodingGorilla:how do i check that?and even if the data is cached how do i remove it?

Comment: @HarishViswanathan Put a breakpoint at `dr = cmd.ExecuteReader()` and inspect the DataReader to see if there are any results in it.  You may have to use the immediate window to call dr.Read() and look to see if it returns true or false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must fire a commit after you delete rows in sqlplus.

If you delete and run a select, you won't see any rows in that session.
But your rows are not really deleted yet.

They will be deleted from the actual table only after you ask sqlplus to commit your changes.

This is needed cause oracle doesn't auto-commit by default.

Comment: i had no idea that there something called commit !thanx a lot guys!i really learned something new today :D